# Android, Intent doesn't see a .class

Tags: android, android-intent

I`ve got a problem with Intents. I have two java classes in same packages and only to the one I can go using Intent

```
public void goToSetDataActivity(View view) {
    Intent goToSetDataIntent = new Intent(this, SetDataActivity.class);
    startActivity(goToSetDataIntent);
}

public void goToSetAdditionalDataActivity(View view) {
  Intent goToSetAdditionalDataInteny = new Intent(this, SetAdditionalData.class)
}
```

Secound method doeasn't work with an error "Cannot resolve symbol "SetAdditionalData"

Comment: Please add some code, Like import line for SetAdditionalData class. Did you try to build app?

Comment: package com.example.user.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.Intent;
  

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
 ..... usual code + there two methods
  }

Comment: Is SetAdditionalData class extends Activity? please post some code about your class SetAdditionalData so we can help you.

Answer (score 2):

```
public void goToSetDataActivity(View view) {
    Intent goToSetDataIntent = new Intent(this, SetDataActivity.class);
    startActivity(goToSetDataIntent);
}

public void goToSetAdditionalDataActivity(View view) {
  Intent goToSetAdditionalDataInteny = new Intent(this, SetAdditionalData.class);
startActivity( goToSetAdditionalDataInteny);
}
```

And check you spelling for the class name. Also there need to `;` after 7th line

Answer (score 0):

Check your spelling first, most of the time that is the problem:

```
 startActivity(goToSetDataIntent); 

public void goToSetAdditionalDataActivity(View view) {
  Intent **goToSetAdditionalDataInteny** = new Intent(this, SetAdditionalData.class)
}
```

The last letter in the intent ends in Inteny, likely not correct, likely meant Intent.

Anytime you get the error, "Cannot resolve symbol 'SetAdditionalData'" it means it cannot find what it is looking for, meaning it is either likely spelled wrong or placed in the wrong location (IE being called before it is declared)

Comment: You have to start activity like in first method like this:

Comment: The problem is not with the variable name but with the class name

Comment: Thanks for 'Inteny' but the problems is that name of class is the same:

Answer (score 0):

```
public void goToSetDataActivity(View view) {
    Intent goToSetDataIntent = new Intent(this, SetDataActivity.class);
    startActivity(goToSetDataIntent);
}

public void goToSetAdditionalDataActivity(View view) {
  Intent goToSetAdditionalDataInteny = new Intent(this,   SetAdditionalData.class);
```

//you need this
startActivity(goToSetDataIntent);

```
}
```

Comment: yes thanks but there is problem with SetAdditionalData.class); with says he doeanst recognive SetAddtionalData.class and there is that class  in package ....

Comment: did u wrote that class corectly ? tha name for SetAddtionalData